# How can we make four distinct lists of books so that the total number of pages in the books on each list are equal?

Tags: combinatorics

I have $15$ books each with between $300$ to $400$ pages. How can we make four distinct lists of books  so that the total number of pages in the books on each list are equal ?

Can anyone please give me a hint to proceed ?

Comment: It looks like someone changed the numbers on this problem - you should be able to find more lists! Maybe they did it before posting it for you to repost here. It seems risky to repost an assignment question though - what will the student do if you copy my answer to my question? I assume they think you are solving the problems instead of asking volunteers at MSE to do it.

Answer (score 2):

A list of four books has at least $4\cdot300=1200$ pages. A list of three books has at most $3\cdot400=1200$ pages. So there can only be one solution in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing 7 books gives the largest number of lists since the binomial coefficients are unimodal, so the largest is $\binom{15}{7}$ or $\binom{15}{8}$. A list of 7 books has from $2107$ to $2793$ (inclusive) total pages, and so there are less than $700$ possibilities. We can show that $\binom{15}{7}>9\cdot700$ using Stirling's approximation, hence we can find $10$ distinct lists of $7$ books each with the same total number of pages.